# PHP Регистр имени файла и ошибка 404

Tags: php

Столкнулась с проблемой при скачивании файла, имя которого написано с разным регистром, для примера patch-ruRU-103.MPQ.

Ссылку для скачивания получаю через метод по ссылке /download/patch-ruRU-103.MPQ

```
public function downloadAction($params)
    {
        $file = ROOT."/updates/".$params;
        if (file_exists($file)) {
            header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
            header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
            header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($file).'"');
            header('Expires: 0');
            header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
            header('Pragma: public');
            header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
            readfile($file);
            exit;
        }
    }
```

Если файл написан с маленьких букв, он скачивается без проблем, в моем случае, выдает ошибку 404, файл не найден. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это решить?

Comment: Это не нужно решать. Если имя файла написано в нижнем регистре, то нужно запрашивать его в нижнем регистре. Если хотите верхний регистр - переименуйте его.

Comment: оно записано точно так же, как я его запрашиваю, но возникает ошибка, если переименую его в нижний регистр и сам файл и значение в базе, и вызову ссылкой, то скачается

Comment: А, в каком регистре файл запрашивает браузер? Что говорит раздел "Network" в инструментах разработчика?

Comment: @Streletz после загрузки файла на сервер, имя записывается в базу, как в оригинале, ссылка генерируется точно с таким же именем, файл так же имеет то же имя, вкладка Network пишет 404 на файл, если я его переименую в ниж. регистр, то он скачается

Comment: Это Вы уже писали. Только я Вам говорю совсем о другом. Когда браузер пытается скачать файл по ссылке, как он его запрашивает? На упомянутой вкладке можно посмотреть подробные сведения.

Comment: @Streletz есть get запрос  `$route->get('/download/:file[a-z0-9-.]:', function ($params) {
    return Application::getPage('server::download', $params);
});`  в него кладется имя файла, далее, метод достает из нужной папки файл

Comment: @Streletz что именно из вкладки Вам необходимо?

Comment: Вообще-то информация со вкладки "Network" нужна не мне, а Вам, чтобы локализовать ошибку. Объясняю в последний раз. Сравните, то что запрашивает браузер (`Request URL`), с тем, что есть на стороне сервера. Не удивлюсь, если где-то выполняется [нормализация URL](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F_URL).

Comment: @Streletz Request URL такой же, к которому обращаюсь (http://launcher.wowsuite.ru//download//patch-ruRU-103.MPQ) , Status Code 404 ... просто, я не могу понять, как это поможет в регистре?

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решилась так:

```
/download/:file[A-Za-z0-9-.]:
```